# Bash script sed usage causing issues in ZSH

Tags: bash, shell, sed, zsh

I have a Bash script that I use to pull in several repos to create a new instance of our project workflow, which carries out a number of string replacements based on information provided from the command line.

A colleague uses ZSH and has been experiencing issues that seem to be as a result of the use of `sed` in the script. Specifically it seems to be that it's not processing the regex? For example...

```
    # Author Name.
    if [[ $authorname ]]
    then
    sed -i "" "s/Author Name/$authorname/g" "$file"
    fi
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
sed: can't read "s/Author Name/$authorname/g" : No such file or directory
```

We've found that by adding the `-e` flag the majority of the string replacement errors go away, however he still gets a number of 'not found' errors...

```
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
```

Is there a better way to carry out the string replacement that is both Bash and ZSH friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumable you are using GNU `sed`, which does not take `-i ""` like patterns for editing the file in place like BSD `sed`.

From `man sed`:

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

You need to remove the space in between:

```
sed -i"" "s/Author Name/$authorname/g" "$file"
```

Or as you are not taking any backup, simply do:

```
sed -i "s/Author Name/$authorname/g" "$file"
```

Comment: This will fail on *BSD, though. There isn't really a portable way to use `-i` across platforms.

Comment: Also, `sed -i"" ...` is *exactly* equivalent to `sed -i ...`. `-i""`, after quote removal, is the same word as `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

if you do that:

```
sed -i "" "s/Author Name/$authorname/g" "$file"
```

First argument `""` is considered as the regex, and the others as the files, hence the error you're getting.

Just remove the `""` of your command line.

Alternately, if your commands are dynamic you can do:

```
sed -i -e "" -e "s/Author Name/$authorname/g" "$file"
```

first regex will be ignored.